# Loop help C++ test

Tags: c++, for-loop

i have a test and i get this question : https://prnt.sc/ip3z7n 
and this is my answer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int grade,counter=0;
    for(int counter;counter<10;counter++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the grade: ";
        cin>>grade;
        if(grade>=60)
        cout<<"Passed \n";
        else
        cout<<"Failed \n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This invokes undefined behavior. Your loop declaration of an indeterminate `counter` hides the outer one that is actually initialized to zero. Get rid of the `int counter` in the loops decl.

Comment: I don't see you asking any question. Please reread the guidelines for asking good questions, yours is far from clear.

Comment: When declaring the for loop, don't use int counter again. Since you already initialized counter before, you should just use for(counter;counter<10;counter++)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int grade=0;
    for(int counter = 0;counter<10;counter++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the grade: ";
        cin>>grade;
        if(grade>=60)
        cout<<"Passed \n";
        else
        cout<<"Failed \n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wait so my answer is correct or not?

Comment: it is not, you have two counters

Comment: so i just need to change the counter thing right? and everything else is good?

Comment: yep you are good to go

Comment: okay thanks for the help , can i ask you a question i can't solve it http://prntscr.com/ip7w3d

Comment: yes but you have to ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int grade, counter = 0;
    for(; counter < 10; counter++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the grade: ";
        cin>>grade;
        if(grade >= 60)
          cout<<"Passed \n";
        else
          cout<<"Failed \n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

According to the question, `counter` is declare and initialized before the loop, so there is no need to define and initialize it in the loop.